# Apple Mach-O Linker error *for me being messy*

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

So I was just looking around at some options, and pressed some 'Product' options. I'm not sure which one made me get this, but i think it was 'Analyze.'

Anyway, the error is 
[image]

As you can see on the bottom, it says some file is missing. I went to that directory, and [image]
its here. Except I can't access it. I tried sending the project to a friend, who compiled and ran the project without getting the error. I'm pretty much blank on this one, can someone tell me what's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say it's there, but your screen shot shows that it's not there.  It's looking for a folder named `LNG Converter.app` in that `Debug-iphonesimulator` folder, but your screen shot shows that there is no folder named `LNG Converter.app` there.

Try cleaning the build folder.  Hold the option key, and choose Product > Clean Build Folder.

Comment: Great, that fixed it. The project has been moved a lot back and forth, so I probably just had a mess of files in my system.